# open files saved with R's `saveRDS` (serialization interface) with stata

Tags: r, stata

generally I prefer to save my R object using `saveRDS` so that I can later reassign them to a particular variable using `df= readRDS(...)`. Sometimes I want to do something in stata though. So is there a way to open the files saved with `saveRDS` in stata?

Comment: Why not use `foreign::write.dta`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing right now. But I have many `saveRDS` files and sometimes I would like to use them in other software (mainly stata) without first opening R and resaving them. `dta` files are also  nearly 10x as large in my experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having to read variables stored in R's binary format from Stata is an indication that your data management strategy is wonky.  If you want to read data with multiple formats, then you should use a non-platform-specific format.  That usually means a text-based format ([CSV](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/read.table) or tab-delimited or [XML](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XML/docs/xmlTreeParse) or [JSON](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RJSONIO/docs/fromJSON)), or a database, or a well-documented standardised binary format ([HDF5](http://master.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html)).

To fix your situation, you need a `resave` function that reads in an RDS file and outputs it in a new format.  Something like

```
resave <- function(infile)
{
  x <- readRDS(infile)
  outfile <- sub("\\.rds$", "\\.csv", infile)
  write.csv(x, outfile)
}
```

Another possible strategy is to convert the file with `foreign::write.dta` on an as-needed basis.  This is described on the [StatLore blog](https://statlore.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/how-to-call-r-from-stata/).  It may be a better strategy if you only occasionally use Stata.

The idea is that you have a batch file of R code that resaves the file, then you use Stata's `shell` command to call R in batch mode.

```
shell "<path to R>\R.exe" CMD BATCH resaveAsDta.R
```

Then you can `use` the DTA file as normal.